# How to query a collection in Firestore and aggregate the documen into `per day`, `per week`?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, nosql-aggregation

My goal is to aggregate the document into `per day`, `per week`.

document template stored in Firestore.

```
document = {
  iat: new Date() // Wed Aug 26 2020 HH:MM:SS GMT+... (... Time),
  bill: PropTypes.number,
}
```

The expected output is

```
data = {
  labels: [
            08/26/2020,
            08/27/2020,
            ...
          ],
  datasets: [
    ...
    data: [
            bill1 + bill2,
            bill3 + bill4 + bill5,
            bill6,
            bill7 + bill8
          ],
  ],
}
```

What I've tried. The output is per document.

```
firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection("tickets")
  .orderBy("exp")
  .get()
  .then((snapshot) => {
    if (!snapshot.empty) {

      setData({
        labels: snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
          const data = doc.data();
          const exp = data.exp ? new Date(data.exp.seconds * 1000 + data.exp.milliseconds).toString().split(" ").slice(1, 5).join(" ") : null;

          return exp;
        }),
        datasets: [
          {
            data: snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
              const data = doc.data();
              const bill = data.bill ? data.bill : null;

              return bill;
            }),
          },
        ],
      });
```

**tl:dr**

The problem I saw is, it is easier to merge the `iat` key into per day or per hour. While it is hard to merge the `bill` key based on the merging of the `iat` key.

What I can think about now is solving it with nested logic and I imagine it would be cryptic, heads up if you have simpler solution.

I will back in a hour after I found a solution.

Thank you, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, a cryptic one.

```
// explaining how dataReduced works.
// acc / accumulator intially does not hold value.
// Therefore, on the first iteration acc[key] = acc[key] returns undefined so we fill it with a value { bill: 0, ...cur }.
// accumulator value is remembered across iteration.
// For comparison, in for loop statement, accumulator is similar to `let i = 0; for (i = 0; condition, execution);`
console.log(
  dataDateEqualized.reduce((acc, { bill, ...cur }) => {
    console.log("acc ", acc, " bill ", bill, " cur ", cur);
    const key = Object.entries(cur).join();

    console.log("acc ", acc, " key ", key, " before ", acc[key]);
    acc[key] = acc[key] || { bill: 0, ...cur };

    console.log("acc ", acc, " after ", acc[key], " bill ", bill);
    return (acc[key].bill += bill); // this is intentional
  }, {})
);
```

```
      firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection("tickets")
        .orderBy("exp")
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
          if (!snapshot.empty) {
            const data = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
              return doc.data();
            });

            // console.log(data);

            const dataDateEqualized = data.map((data) => {
              const date = new Date(
                new Date(data.exp.seconds * 1000).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)
              );
              const bill = data.bill;

              return { "exp": date, bill };
            });

            // console.log(dataDateEqualized);

            const dataReduced = Object.values(
              dataDateEqualized.reduce((acc, { bill, ...r }) => {
                const key = Object.entries(r).join("-");
                acc[key] = acc[key] || { ...r, bill: 0 };
                return (acc[key].bill += bill, acc);
              }, {})
            );

            // console.log(dataReduced);

            // console.log(dataReduced.map(data => data.exp.toString().split(" ").slice(1, 4).join(" ")))

            setData({
              labels: dataReduced.map(data => data.exp.toString().split(" ").slice(1, 4).join(" ")),
              datasets: [
                {
                  label: "Revenue Report",
                  fill: false,
                  lineTension: 0.1,
                  backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
                  borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                  borderCapStyle: "butt",
                  borderDash: [],
                  borderDashOffset: 0.0,
                  borderJoinStyle: "miter",
                  pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                  pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                  pointBorderWidth: 1,
                  pointHoverRadius: 5,
                  pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                  pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                  pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
                  pointRadius: 1,
                  pointHitRadius: 10,
                  data: dataReduced.map(data => data.bill),
                }
              ]
            })

          } else if (snapshot.empty) setData();
        })
        .catch((error) => setError(error.message));
```